# Retrieve data from database based on current date and time in SQL Server and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, datetime

I was trying to get the information from my table `Paper_Details` based on current date and 15 min before the current time.

and this is my `SELECT` statement

```
objcmd.CommandText = "Select * from PAPER_DETAILS where ExamDate = Convert(date, getdate()) and StartTime = (Convert(time, getdate()) - 15)"
```

But, it is showing this error

> Type date is not a defined system type.
>   Type time is not a defined system type

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and ASP.NET using VB.

I refer the above query from [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1076143-391-1.aspx)

Thanks in advance !!

**UPDATED**

```
StartTime           |   ExamDate   
____________________|_____________________________
1/1/1900 4:20:00 PM | 7/27/2012 12:00:00 AM
```

The sample data of my table, which will help you to understand the scenario.

From, the above sample data, i wanted that, user can view the information respective to that row only on `7/27/2012` from `4:05:00 PM` to `4:20:00 PM`. I hope, everyone understood my scenario.

Comment: `Time` and `Date` datatypes is not avalible in SQL Server 2005. What datatypes are your columns?

Comment: `datetime` data type, i have used for both columns

Comment: Why do you have two columns? Using `datetime` will let you have both the date and the time in the same column.

Comment: Why you are converting datetime to date?????? GetDate to date?????

Comment: @MikaelEriksson, because, i feel, it would be the better approach  :-)

Comment: Yes, there are scenarios where a separated time column (with an index) could be helpful. It would help a query that wants all exams that happened at a specific time or time interval regardless of the date it happened on. You could solve that with one `datetime` column and a computed column that calculates the seconds since midnight from the `datetime` column. Your current query is best served by the answer from [David Jiboye](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11686081/569436) and that you have the time part in `ExamDate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what, i finally got

```
objcmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM PAPER_DETAILS WHERE ((ExamDate = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))) AND ((DATEPART(minute, GETDATE()) >= DATEPART(minute, DATEADD(MINUTE, - 15, StartTime)))  AND (DATEPART(hh, GETDATE()) = DATEPART(hh, StartTime)) AND (DATEPART(minute, GETDATE()) <= DATEPART(minute, StartTime))    ))"
```

And, verified with some sample data, it works fine.!!!

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their help !!

Answer (score 1):

```
objcmd.CommandText = "Select * from PAPER_DETAILS " + 
                     "where ExamDate=dateadd(dd,0, datediff(dd,0, getDate()) " + 
                     "and (getDate() >= DATEADD(n, -(DATEPART(minute, StartTime) " + 
                     "+ DATEPART(HOUR, StartTime) * 60) - 15, GETDATE())) and  " + 
                     "(GETDATE() <= DATEADD(n, (DATEPART(minute, StartTime) + " + 
                     "DATEPART(HOUR, StartTime) * 60), GETDATE()))"
```

I suppose that you ExamDate doesn't contains time information and thus you need a current date without time information to get an exact comparison.
Also, because your fields are already of DateTime kind, there is no need to CONVERT the results to DateTime

EDIT: Added a very complex test extracting StartTime hour and minutes and using them to build the limits for the checktime. I'm unable to test it, so please let me know if it works.

Comment: in case of date comparison, it works, but when i include the time comparison too, then it doesn't show any records.

Comment: Can you show an example of values present in the column StartTime? Are these values related to the values present in the column ExamDate?

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'`, i'm also checking for this error, meantime you can also check.

Comment: I corrected the code, but now getting this error `Incorrect syntax near 'DATEPART'.`

Comment: Now updated to include the correct parethesis. Still unable to test on real data, but at least, no more syntax error.

Comment: it was getting complex and lengthy too, and it was very hard for me to understand. So, with the help of your code and some other links from stackoverflow and made it for my scenario. I won't forget to give u the credit for this, but sorry, i won't accept your answer. Since, i've posted the answer in less complex and little easier than yours. Thanks again for your help

Comment: No problem. Consider also the possibility to use a stored procedure in which you could easily lower the complexity of inline sql using variables to store the date limits.

Answer (score 0):

Use DATEADD to substract 15minutes from current time

Edited: take away the "CONVERT(DATE.." as you really dont need it and test again

```
SELECT *
  FROM PAPER_DETAILS
 WHERE ExamDate  = GETDATE()
   AND StartTime = DATEADD(MINUTE,-15,GETDATE())
```

Comment: `Type DATE is not a defined system type.`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Select * from PAPER_DETAILS
where ExamDate >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, getdate()) and ExamDate <= getdate()
```

Comment: I did not include your field Starttime, to use the field Starttime refer to the comment by Yaroslav above.

Comment: this doesn't show the correct information, when i include the startTime condition.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare the date and time different-2 then try the following.

```
objcmd.CommandText = "Select * from PAPER_DETAILS " + 
                 "where CONVERT(varchar(20),ExamDate,101)=Convert(varchar(20),getdate(),101) " + 
                 "and CONVERT(varchar(20),StartTime,108)=CONVERT(varchar(20), dateadd(MINUTE,-15,getdate()),108)"
```